# To understand Python's optparse

Tags: python, debugging, arguments

Thank you for quack in pointing out the off-by-one!

The following code is my first attempt in writing code with Optparse.

**How can you fix the following bug in getting the help by Optparse?**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
from optparse import OptionParser


e = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
no = sys.argv[3]

def set_figu(figu):
        sum = 777
        return sum


def main():
        usage = "Usage: negative_bin_base.py <eksponentti> <siirre> <figu>"
        parser = OptionParser(usage)
        parser.add_option("-h", "--help", dest="help",
                        help="get synopsis of parameters")
        # print the output of the work-horse
        print set_figu(no)

        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
        if len(args) < 4:
                parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")
        if options.informative:
                print "reading %s..." % options.help

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

**Example of wrong output with correct number of parameters**

```
python negative_bin_base.py 13 13 332
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "negative_bin_base.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "negative_bin_base.py", line 26, in main
    help="get synopsis of parameters")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/optparse.py", line 1020, in add_option
    self._check_conflict(option)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/optparse.py", line 995, in _check_conflict
    option)
optparse.OptionConflictError: option -h/--help: conflicting option string(s): -h, --help
```

Comment: Look at the optparse module, which makes this considerably easier in the common cases: http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html

Comment: For a one off case handling the args as you are is fine, but investing the time to learn optparse will be worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constructor for `class optparse.OptionParser(...)` has optional named parameter 'add_help_option', which defaults to 'True'. You will have to explicitly reject default help option and message, if you want to provide your own.


`parser = OptionParser(usage, add_help_option=False)`

Comment: if you find 'optparse' too much for what you need, you might also look into 'getopt' http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html

Comment: I was just posting a similar response.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 6):

The bug is that your arguments array includes the name of the script as `sys.argv[0]`.  Thus your `if` is off-by-one:

```
# python sys.argv[0] sys.argv[1] sys.argv[2] sys.argv[3]
if len(sys.argv) < 4:
        sys.exit(usage)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you require, based on your example above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from optparse import OptionParser

def main():
    usage = "Usage: negative_bin_base.py <eksponentti> <siirre> <figu>"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args) != 3:
        parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")
    e = args[0]
    b = args[1]
    no = args[2]
    # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

For using optparse here's what I normally do:

1. separate command line parsing from your main code base for better modularization.
   (Put the processing right after "if __name__ == "__main__"")
2. Let optparse handle your help.
   (Use parser.print_help())
3. Use the optparse constructs, if you don't like them just parse sys.argv yourself.
   (use add_option to define your necessary options)

Here's how I would write your sample using the optparse library:

```
def main():
    print 'Welcome to the main event!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import optparse
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-e", "--eksponentti", dest="eksponentti",
                      help="This is help for <eksponentti>.",
                      default=None)
    parser.add_option("-s", "--siirre", dest="siirre",
                      help="This is help for <siirre>.",
                      default=None)
    parser.add_option("-f", "--figu", dest="figu",
                      help="This is help for <figu>.",
                      default=None)

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if options.eksponentti and options.siirre and options.figu:
        main()
    else:
        print "ERROR -- Expected Arguments not given!"
        parser.print_help()
```

Running this without the necessary options will give the following output:
(It's a little prettier than I can format it here...)

```
ERROR -- Expected Arguments not given! Usage: parm.py [options]

Options:   
    -h, --help            show this help message and exit   
    -e EKSPONENTTI, --eksponentti=EKSPONENTTI This is help for <eksponentti>.   
    -s SIIRRE, --siirre=SIIRRE This is help for <siirre>.   
    -f FIGU, --figu=FIGU  This is help for <figu>.
```

Comment: How do you read this line ` if options.eksponentti and options.siirre and options.figu:`? I am using 3 parameteters in my command and the if-clause is not true.

Comment: monkut has changed how your command line options are handled, he has named the options for you.  For example, `python negative_bin_base.py -e 13 -s 13 -f 332`.

Comment: Thanks, john.  Yes, options.<option> is where items created with 'add_option' are accessed.  Using the 'add_option' command I'm creating an option and defaulting it to None.  This will evaluate to 'False' in the if-clause.  So if all the options are not provided you will see the error message and 'help' will be displayed.